# Screen readers and adding a checkbox to a button group while still allowing multiple selections

Tags: java, swing, accessibility, screen-readers, buttongroup

To make a GUI accessible to screen readers, check boxes should belong to a button group.  However, if you want to allow multiple check boxes to be selected simultaneously, you cannot add them to a javax.swing.ButtonGroup as turning "on" one of those buttons turns off all other buttons in the group.

Is there some other type of "button group" that you should add check boxes to in order to make a GUI accessible to screen readers?

Comment: I think that not possible, have to create own logics, own ButtonGroup

Answer (score 0):

Make a new type of `ButtonGroup` allowing exclusions:

```
public class ExclusiveButtonGroup extends ButtonGroup {
    private ArrayList<ButtonModel> exclusives;

    public ExclusiveButtonGroup(AbstractButton... exclusives){
        for(AbstractButton b : exclusives)
            this.exclusives.add(b.getModel);
    }

@Override
    public void setSelected(ButtonModel model, boolean select) {
        if(!exclusives.contains(model))
            super.setSelected(model, select);
    }
```